# LLVM instrumentation

Tags: llvm

Recently, I am doing some research with `LLVM`.

At first, I want to write a pass to instrument `.bc` file.

Thus, it will record the execution path of the basic block of my `.bc` file.

Then, I want to term this `.bc` file into `.exe` file. Please give me your suggestions and if you have some examples for instrumentation of LLVM, please show me.

Comment: Maybe LLVM Tutorial can help you to get familiar with it. http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

LLVM already comes with a number of instrumentation tools built-in. Take a look in the `lib/Transforms/Instrumentation` directory in the source tree.

One of the best known passes is [Address Sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), an instrumentation-based memory error detector (kinda like Valgrind, but significantly faster). Address Sanitizer has a runtime component + a LLVM pass that inserts instrumentation; the pass lives in `lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer.cpp`. There's some description of how it works [on this page](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm).