# Calculate number of times each instruction could be called at run-time

Tags: llvm, instrumentation, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0, mcjit

I read the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060434/llvm-instrumentation)

How to calculate number of times each instruction could be called at run-time?

I found at InstrProfiling.cpp file function called `castToIncrementInst`, but this function only calculate total number of instructions. I need the number of calls for each instrucion or basic block